# Mysql update rows column from another row column by conditional

Tags: mysql, sql-update, conditional-statements, row

I've table with similar data:

```
Col1 ; Col2;
G11  ; 112;
G11-1; 0;
G11-2; 2;
G12-2; 111;
```

I would like to update G11- rows col2 with simple G11 col2, but not to modify G12 rows , where there is no simple G12 row.

Comment: So basically you want to Put `G11-1 = 112`  and `G11-2 = 112` and so on

Comment: Yes, I would like to do.

Comment: @Woodyka can you please show the expected results? call me visual, I dont mind :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE 
    tableX AS upd
  JOIN
    tableX AS simple
      ON  simple.Col1 NOT LIKE '%-%'
      AND upd.Col1 LIKE CONCAT(simple.Col1, '-%')
SET
    upd.Col2 = simple.Col2 ;
```

Tested in **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/444b0/1)**

---

This query will show you the intended edits, without updating anything:

```
SELECT upd.Col1, upd.Col2, 
       simple.Col1 AS simpleCol1, simple.Col2 AS New_value
FROM 
    tableX AS upd
  JOIN
    tableX AS simple
      ON  simple.Col1 NOT LIKE '%-%'
      AND upd.Col1 LIKE CONCAT(simple.Col1, '-%') ;
```

Comment: no error, but not updated rows... :( But it's another way, not where i try to find the good solution.

Comment: (made a copy from my table)
SELECT col2 FROM `table` 
left join table2 on table2.col1=left(table.col1,locate('-',table.col1)-1)

Comment: Try the edited. The `||` operator is used differently depending on the server settings.

Comment: @ypercube it's a nice answer. Just thinking if one uses `instr()` instead of `simple.Col1 NOT LIKE '%-%'` line, do you think there will be a performance gain? In my side `instr(smple.col1,'-',1)>1` seems to run faster..

Comment: @bonCodigo: I really don't know that. If you have done tests, post an answer!

Comment: @Woodyka; The first version works too, if you have [`ANSI` settings](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi) in the server.

Answer (score 2):

Credit to @Ypercube for creating the sqlfidle. Here is another way to do the validation using `instr`. Seems a little faster.

- [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6180/2).

Just the select query only. Update query can also have the `instr` syntax.

```
SELECT *
FROM tableX ;

SELECT upd.Col1, upd.Col2, 
       simple.Col1 AS simpleCol1, simple.Col2 AS New_value
FROM 
    tableX AS upd
  JOIN
    tableX AS simple
      ON  instr(simple.Col1 ,'-') = 0
      AND upd.Col1 LIKE CONCAT(simple.Col1, '-%') ;
```

Results:

```
COL1    COL2    SIMPLECOL1  NEW_VALUE
G11-1   0   G11         112
G11-2   2   G11         112
```

Comment: Nice! Yes, a little bit faster! Thanks you too!

Comment: Glad to hear Woodyka, and please accept @ypercube 's answer. So the system get's updated and others in the community will know your question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

Ypercube's solution is correct and clean, and the idea of bonCodigo is nice! But both of them can be simplified a little more. If this condition returns true:

```
upd.Col1 LIKE CONCAT(simple.Col1, '-%')
```

it means that `upd.Col1` does contain (at least) one `-` more than `simple.Col1`, and in case that just one `-` is permitted, like in your sample data, `simple.Col1` has no `-` already, so both these conditions are redundant:

```
ON simple.Col1 NOT LIKE '%-%'
ON instr(simple.Col1 ,'-') = 0
```

But I like the idea of using `INSTR`, it can't always substitute a `LIKE`, but when it can, it can be faster. I would write SELECT query like this:

```
SELECT
  upd.Col1,
  upd.Col2, 
  simple.Col1 AS simpleCol1,
  simple.Col2 AS New_value
FROM 
  tableX AS upd JOIN tableX AS simple
  ON instr(upd.Col1, concat(simple.Col1, '-'))
```

and UPDATE query would be very similar. Since this is only an integration on others answers, I'm giving a +1 to everyone for the ideas :)